# How to turn off predictive text in QLineEdit on Android?

Tags: android, c++, qt5

I'm trying to build an app for both android and linux using Qt 5.12. It's necessary to read the current text in `QLineEdit` every time a character is typed in. On Android 6 device the current text part shows underlined while typing and the predictor is shown.
I only get the signals `QLineEdit::textChanged` on every `Space` or `Return`. Same behavior for signals `QLineEdit::textEdited` `QLineEdit::cursorPositionChanged`.
Disabling both `QCompleter` and `QValidator` didn't help.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(nullptr);
    ui->lineEdit->setValidator(nullptr);
}


void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    //just for demonstration
    ui->listWidget->addItem(arg1);
}
```

Qt 5.12.6
Android 6.0.1/Android 7.1.1 Google Keyboard

Many thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested or are facing the same problem: `QLinedit::setInputMethodHints()` is the right choice.

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->setInputMethodHints(Qt::ImhNoPredictiveText|Qt::ImhNoAutoUppercase|Qt::ImhNoEditMenu);
}
```